# Sin and holiness

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, belief, karma

Can any god among 330 million  Hindu gods  save a sinner and make him/her holy? Please give references from  Hindu Scriptures. (Not your own version as a Hindu  but quotation from an authentic religious book.)

Comment: There is only one Supreme Brahman and all 33 types (koti means type or crore in Sanskrit) of Gods are Brahman's different aspects or attributes. There are many methods described in Scriptures to get rid of Sins. You should be precise of what sin. Visiting Kashi and taking a dip in Ganga will remove almost all Sins. But important thing, you should be  devoted to Lord while taking dip in Ganga and should never resort to those bad deeds again. You can't cheat Lord. Else, there's no use in taking dip in Ganga and Visiting Kashi

Comment: Yes God can save a sinner and make Him Holy. Otherwise that entity cannot be God isnt it? God by definition is All-Powerful. Vaishnavas believe Vishnu can do it. ISKCON believes Krishna can do it. Shaivites believe Shiva can do it. While Shakteyas believe Lalithambika can do it. Advaitins believe you are never a sinner, you are Satchidananda, so the question does not apply to Advaitins :). Good luck

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that can for sure remove all the sins committed by a person is Sharanagati, Surrendering to the Lotus feet of Lord Shriman Narayana.

Shrimad Bhagwad Gita Chapter 18 verse Shloka 66

> सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज, मामेकम् शरनम् व्रज । अहम् त्वा सर्व पापेभ्यो मोक्श्यामि मा शुच​

meaning

> Completely relinquishing all Dharmas, take refuge in Me alone. I will release you from all sins, grieve not.

Translating word by word

**'Relinquishing all Dharmas’**  means the complete abandonment of the notion of agency, proprietorship, results etc., in the practice of Karma, Jñāna and Bhakti Yogas which are the means (dharmas) for attaining the highest good when done as Divine Service.

**'I will release you from all sins'**
means that I will free you from all obstacles that
prevent you from attaining Me; consisting of [the karmic reaction of] innumerable acts of doing what is forbidden and neglecting what is bidden. Accumulating from beginingless times [the reactions of] these deeds cause obstacles in spiritual development.

**Alternative Interpretation**
Bhakti Yoga is possible only for those individuals
who love the Lord intensely and who are free from all negative karma. One’s karmic
reactions (sins) are obstacles in the path of developing loving devotion and are so
numerous that the expiatory rites which would exculpate them could not possibly be
performed in the limited time of one life span. Arjuna therefore thought that he was
incapable of practicing Bhakti Yoga. To remedy Arjuna's despondency the Lord said:
'Completely relinquishing all Dharmas, take refuge in Me alone.' The term ‘Dharma’ used
in this context would apply to the expiatory rites. So in order to successfully commence
Bhakti Yoga, surrender to Me alone. I am supremely compassionate, the refuge of all
without distinction, an ocean of maternal solicitude for those dependent on Me. I will
release you from all sins, which have been explained as obstacles to the practice of Bhakti
Yoga — grieve not.

**As TheDestroyer mentioned you have to be completly loyal to yourself and god,you should feel guilty for committing those sins, then and only then there is meaning to sharanagati, you should love Shriman Narayana who is supreme bramhan**
 or love nirguna bramhan if you think advaita is correct

[Source](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/ramanuja_gita_bhashya.pdf)

[Yet another Interpretation](http://asitis.com/18/66.html)

Comment: I think you should mention just Lord instead of "Srimannarayana". That would be a valid point point for all Hindus.

Comment: @The Destroyer - lord seems to be like an English word, srimannarayana feels like so close .